# Angular 2 router attaches question mark in URL

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am facing a strange issue in my Angular 4 project. I am trying to navigate to a path through code (on button click). I am using `router.navigate()` method as follows to accomplish the job --

```
this._router.navigate(["/employeeDetails", selectedEmployee.EmployeeId]);
```

Where `selectedEmployee.EmployeeId` is a number.
The navigation happens but I am getting a very weird thing in the URL. Initially the URL shows as follows --
`http://localhost:4200/?employeeDetails/170` and then the `?` sign vanishes from the URL and the required page is loaded.

Can anyone please tell me why the `?` sign is coming in the URL. Ideally it should load the respective component for the route `"/employeeDetails"` without refreshing the page. I also tried the code without `/` as follows but no help.

```
this._router.navigate(["/employeeDetails", selectedEmployee.EmployeeId]);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason could be a missing `action="/formsubmit"`.  When Chrome tries to send a GET request without it this it appends a `?`to the current URL.

Try the below for your submit action:

```
onSubmitAction(event){
    event.preventDefault()
}
```

- It is not an issue with the Angular router

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Abhishek, that really helped. I did what you said and it worked out.

Answer (score 13):

None of the previous answer gives the correct answer even thought some of them work! But all put a patch without acting on the cause of the event we have.

The **solution** is to set the **type="button"** to the button element, because by default the form identifies the button as *type="submit"* if not specified and triggers the submit action.

However thanks because the combination of the answers helped me to find the real cause!

Comment: This seems to be a more appropriate solution.

Answer (score 4):

To have que question mark in URL with angular 2 (4,5,6) for parameters:

```
this.router.navigate(['/companie'], { queryParams: { type: 'firstRegister' }});
```

you will get:

```
https://myurl/#/companie?type=firstRegister
```

---

To have the classic parameter, it is:

```
this.router.navigate(['/companie', { type: 'firstRegister' }])
```

you will get:

```
https://myurl/#/companie;type=firstRegister
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Solved it by adding this action to my form tag:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that your injected `_router: Router` in your components constructor like this:

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {}
```

Change this:

```
this._router.navigate(["/employeeDetails", selectedEmployee.EmployeeId]);
```

to this:

```
this._router.navigate(['/employeeDetails', selectedEmployee.EmployeeId]);
```

or this:

```
this._router.navigate(['/employeeDetails/' + selectedEmployee.EmployeeId]);
```

In your routing file you should have something like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: 'employeeDetails/:id', component: YourComponent },
  ...
];
```